# If I have a cdef or cpdef function which uses yield, what type should it be?

Tags: python-3.x, cython, yield, typing

Okay, I have a generator function (a function which uses the yield statement).

Specifically, it is a part of a Cythonized thing I'm working on to have Python play Sudoku. (Yes, that is trivial, but it's what I'm working on right now and it is relevant to other things.)

That's part 1 of establishing context. Part 2 is that the Sudoku grid is stored as a list of lists of Cells (extension type because I can do so, for this it might as well be a smart integer that can work out what it could, and even should, be based on the other instances that have been fed to it - anyway).

Here's the portion of the code in question:

```
cpdef box_gen(self):
    cdef:
        unsigned char y1, x, y2
        list box
    for y1 in range(0,9,3):
        for x in range(0,9,3):
            box = []
            for y2 in range(y1,y1+3):
                box.extend(self.grid[y2][x:x+3])
            yield [cell.c for cell in box]
cpdef row_gen(self):
    cdef:
        list row
    for row in self.grid:
        yield [x.c for x in row]
cpdef col_gen(self):
    cdef:
        char i
    for i in range(9):
        yield [row[i].c for row in self.grid]
```

Oh, also, the numeric value of a Cell (or 0 if they has yet to be determined or assigned) is stored in the attribute 'c'.

So: what should I type these functions as? Is there a type I need to cimport from cpython? Is there something I need to grap using a `cdef extern` block?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you could use yield with anything other than a def function. This is a Python feature which doesn't have a direct C equivalent. (I haven't tried though so it's always possible it might be possible)

Comment: I guess not much changed since this conversation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/DSJ_DlwCHHw. So you still have to use def-functions with generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work - you can only use generators with `def` functions.

To explain why it doesn't really make sense for them to work with `cdef` functions: `cdef` functions produce something that can be directly translated into a C function signature

```
cdef int f(float y):
   #...
```

becomes (with some name mangling)

```
int f(float y) {
   // ...
}
```

Generators (and also inner functions) by necessity have some internal state to keep track of where in the closure it is and what variables have been changed.  This would be represented in C as at least two functions

```
 some_opaque_structure_type* prepare_generator_f(float y) {
    // ...
 }

 int use_generator_f(some_opaque_structure_type* s) {
     // ...
 }
```

(And this ignores how to signal that iteration has finished, or how to [pass data back into the iterator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), or the [`result = yield from some_other_generator` syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/))

Although none of this would be impossible to implement, it would break the link of "`cdef` functions have a clear C signature and thus can be passed as a C function pointer or readily be used by user-defined C code". `cdef` functions have a set of limitations that enable them to be called slightly more efficiently from Cython, and thus it makes sense that they can't do everything that Python `def` functions can do.

---

Just use a `def` function.

Comment: A Cython noob here, Is there anyway that one can use an equivalent of "yield" inside a cdef function ? Per my use case, using def with "yield" is simply taking orders of magnitude more time, so I wanted to cythonize everything possible. Appreciate your thoughts :)

Comment: @AmithAdiraju I don't think so - yield and generators are very much "Python" features. You could always refactor it: Cython implements generators by saving the local state from inside the function on a struct so you could do the same yourself. You need a function to initialize the struct and a function to get the next value based on the struct. It isn't nearly as nice syntax as using yield, but it'll have the same effect.